# Lost all sound daemons and controls, and pulseaudio does not restart

Tags: unity, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I was debugging an issue with my Bluetooth headset -- the volume control would reset every time they connected. I added the following lines to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

After this I ran `pulseaudio -k`, and the volume control disappeared from the top bar. The volume slider in the drop down menu is empty, and `pavucontrol` reported that it was waiting for a connection. **Pulseaudio refused to restart due to a PID issue, even on a reboot**

Because of this, I purged `~/.pulse-cookie`, `~/.config/pulse/cookie`, `~/.config/pulse/*.db`, and `/tmp/pulse*`.

**Now I can start the `pulseaudio` daemon, but the volume control in the top bar is gone, `pavucontrol` reports `'Establishing connection to pulseaudio, please wait...'`, and the volume slider in the dropdown bar is still empty**

How do I resolve this? Alternately, what logs do I check? Doing `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio -vvvvvv` again, gives me:

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 11.1
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-cQQZLF/pulseaudio-11.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 4.15.0-117-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 20:02:41 UTC 2020
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 4.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/alx/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-11.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

`dmesg` shows nothing. I have tried using `htop` to kill the existing pulseaudio daemons, which are:

```
gdm       2611  0.0  0.1 1150728 11808 ?       Ssl  16:29   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
alx      10684  0.0  0.0 235036  5728 ?        S<   17:03   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

They do not respond to `-15`, `-2` or even `-9`.

**How do I get my sound system back?**

Answer (score 0):

After three reboots, I removed `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`. Another reboot and it works.

In `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, the line:

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

is guarded, it wasn't in my local `default.pa`. My guess is that `pulseaudio` was trying to start what is perhaps a nonexistent module, or maybe waiting for it to load.